# Jquery, add text within <div> tag (within brackets), is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to turn this:
`<div class="foo" id="bar"></div>`
into this: `<div class="foo" id="bar" style="color:black" "whatever else comes in mind" ></div>`

not just css or classes etc, but whatever else comes in mind, can jquery get an element from id or class and add stuff within its < >?
is it possible?

Comment: if it is an attribute pair, you can use `.attr()`

Comment: Just out of curiosity why would you ever want to do that ?

Comment: grab the parent element and find your div, then you can amend or remove and then add the specific html content with the correct attributes.

Comment: apart from attributes and whitespace there is no legal content inside the angled brackets. `attr` is your friend, `replace` if you want to tamper with whitespace (besides lint-ing, why would you want to do the latter ?).

Comment: @PatsyIssa im making a small parallax site using the skrollr plugin. I wanted to add some weird attributes in the form of `data-xxx="blahblah"` ended up doing it as answered by @melanciaUK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to add attributes, because any other kind of text added would make the markup invalid. So you can achieve it like that:

**Multiple attributes at once**

```
$(foo).attr({myNewAttribute1: "myNewAttributeValue1", myNewAttribute2: "myNewAttributeValue2"});
```

**One attribute a time**

```
$(foo).attr("myNewAttribute", "myNewAttributeValue");
```

Comment: to set multiple attributes at once: `$(foo).attr({myNewAttribute1: "myNewAttributeValue1", myNewAttribute2: "myNewAttributeValue2"});`. generalization left to the reader ... ;-)

Comment: @collapsar well reminded. I'll complement the answer. Cheers! :)

Comment: sorry, forgot the braces; added to comment and answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could be a workaround

```
var $bar = $('#bar')

$bar.replaceWith('<div class="'+$bar.attr('class')+'" id="'+$bar[0].id+'" style="color:black" "whatever else comes in mind" ></div>');
```

(I went with the assumption that you don't want to add a new attribute)

Comment: but you _do_ add a new attribute, even if you don't use the api, don't you ?

Comment: @collapsar can't really say that `"whatever else comes in mind"` is an attribute

Comment: If what the OP is adding is not an attribute, it would make the markup invalid.

Comment: It's up to the OP then. Haha

Comment: i ended up using attributes but thanks for the idea, your answer covers the "whatever comes in mind" part

Answer (score 0):

find the parent of `<div class="foo" id="bar"></div>` then

```
$('#parent').html("<div class="foo" id="bar" style="color:black" "whatever else comes in mind" ></div>");
```